# Thread Art Generation that Creates Embroidery Files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a thread art generator that creates thread patterns from images. Mine is a bit different as it outputs an embroidery file (It embroiders quite nicely, though the settings need a lot of tweaking and the output file needs resizing) The code is quite inefficient, but that's python for you.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageDraw, ImageEnhance
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
from skimage import feature
from skimage.morphology import dilation

from pyembroidery import *

#Variables
base_image = "test.jpg"
thread_count = 1000
nail_count = 600
min_dist = 30
contrast = 0.8
edge = 2
edge_size = 0
sizing = 5

def points_gen(r, n):
    t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n, endpoint=False)
    x = (r - 1) * np.cos(t) + r 
    y = (r - 1) * np.sin(t) + r 
    return np.c_[x.astype(int), y.astype(int)]

def plotLineLow(x0, y0, x1, y1):
    dx = x1 - x0
    dy = y1 - y0
    yi = 1
    if dy < 0:
        yi = -1
        dy = -dy

    D = (2 * dy) - dx
    y = y0

    for x in range(x0, x1+1):
        yield (x, y)
        if D > 0:
            y = y + yi
            D = D + (2 * (dy - dx))
        else:
            D = D + 2*dy

def plotLineHigh(x0, y0, x1, y1):
    dx = x1 - x0
    dy = y1 - y0
    xi = 1
    if dx < 0:
        xi = -1
        dx = -dx

    D = (2 * dx) - dy
    x = x0

    for y in range(y0, y1 + 1):
        yield (x, y)
        if D > 0:
            x = x + xi
            D = D + (2 * (dx - dy))
        else:
            D = D + 2*dx

def bresenham_line(x0, y0, x1, y1):
    if abs(y1 - y0) < abs(x1 - x0):
        if x0 > x1:
            return plotLineLow(x1, y1, x0, y0)
        else:
            return plotLineLow(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    else:
        if y0 > y1:
            return plotLineHigh(x1, y1, x0, y0)
        else:
            return plotLineHigh(x0, y0, x1, y1)

def white_to_transparency(img):
    x = np.asarray(img.convert('RGBA')).copy()

    x[:, :, 3] = (255 * (x[:, :, :3] != 255).any(axis=2)).astype(np.uint8)

    return Image.fromarray(x)

def is_close(n, center, offset, length):
  lo = (center - offset) % length
  hi = (center + offset) % length
  if lo < hi:
      return lo <= n <= hi
  else:
      return n >= lo or n <= hi

def embroider(final_line):
    pattern = EmbPattern()

    pattern.add_block([line[0] for line in final_line], "black")

    write_dst(pattern, "out.dst", {"long_stitch_contingency":CONTINGENCY_LONG_STITCH_SEW_TO})

#Open Image
img = Image.open(base_image) 
img = img.resize((500, 500))
size = img.size

#Remove Trasperency
img = img.convert('RGBA')
background = Image.new('RGBA', size, (255,255,255))
img = Image.alpha_composite(background, img)

#Make B&W
img = img.convert("L")

#edge magic
edges = feature.canny(np.array(img), sigma=edge)
for _ in range(edge_size): edges = dilation(edges)
edges = white_to_transparency((ImageOps.invert(Image.fromarray((edges * 255).astype(np.uint8)).convert("L"))))

#Make RGBA
img = img.convert('RGBA')

#Add edge
img = Image.alpha_composite(img, edges)

#Make B&W Again
img = img.convert("L")

#Circle Crop
mask = Image.new('L', size, 255)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
draw.ellipse((0, 0) + size, fill=1)
img = ImageOps.fit(img, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
img.paste(0, mask=mask)

#Contraster
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(img)
img = enhancer.enhance(contrast)
img.show()

points = points_gen(img.size[0] / 2, nail_count)
base_point = 0
final_line = []

img = np.asarray(img).copy()
for _ in tqdm(range(thread_count), desc="Calculating Threads"):
    #get avg lumin
    vals = dict()
    max_num = len(points)
    lines = ( (i, bresenham_line(*points[base_point], *point))
            for i, point in enumerate(points) 
            if not is_close(i, base_point, min_dist, max_num))

    for i, line in lines:
        values = [img[value[1]][value[0]] for value in line]
        vals[sum(values)/len(values)] = i

    line = vals[min(vals.keys())]

    final_line.append((tuple(points[base_point]), tuple(points[line])))

    for pixel in bresenham_line(*points[base_point], *points[line]):
        img[pixel[1]][pixel[0]] = 255

    base_point = line

final_line = [[[i * sizing for i in x] for x in line] for line in final_line]
size = size[0]*sizing
output = Image.new('L', (size, size), 255)
out_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(output)

for line in final_line:
    out_draw.line((*line[0], *line[1]), 0)

output.show()
output.save("out.jpg")

embroider(final_line)
```

I would show the embroidered piece, but it's of a family member and quite high in detail. I can show an outputted image of a random model I found on google images.

[image: Thread art image]

There is a weird effect due to how we perceive faces that it looks more like a face the further you are from it.

Comment: What do you want to improve?

Comment: It runs a bit slow, but I've fixed that on my in. I was more wondering if I did something stupid or badly.